# How to pack jre into java app bundle?

Tags: java, macos, bundle, .app

A few days I trying start my java application bundle on Mac. I have learned many articles, tutorials and discussions, but I don't understand if there exist any way to use java from bundle (Java is not installed on OS). I want put different versions of java inside my application bundle. How tell to application loader use jre from my app bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use linux jre, which copied after appbundler ant task performed, on MacOS. Here is [the best article](http://dclunie.blogspot.com/2014/10/keeping-up-with-mac-java-bundling-into.html) about deploying applications as bundles on MacOS.

Comment: Your answer should not just contain a link to a tutorial, but also include the essentials from that source in the answer itself, so your answer does not become useless once the source has disappeared.

Comment: In the source you've linked to, I see a description how a Java jar is bundled as a Mac app, but it does not mention how to include the JRE within that app bundle (which is the question here). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides the best answer for this, see here for instructions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

Take a look at these other questions / answers for more info:

[Using a bundled JRE on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354036/using-a-bundled-jre-on-osx)

[Bundling a private JRE on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699043/bundling-a-private-jre-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Did you try use ant task from Oracle documentation? I have tryed. And yes, I can copy jre from my $JAVA_HOME to Plugins folder, but application isn't starts by JavaAppLauncher which placed into MacOs folder. Can you give some other piece of advice from your own experience?