# Anylogic 7 export standalone model problem

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I want to export my Anylogic 7 model as a standalone java application.

The model export process ends with a positive result.

But when I run .bat file (my OS is windows 7), nothing happens! The black screen activated by the batch file appears and disappears quickly.

Where am I wrong? What could I control in the script of batch file?

I think the problem not concerns my model, because the same result is obtained with an example model from Anylogic 7.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the execution of the .bat file but adding `pause` in the very last line.

It will then run and keep the Window open, so you can see what the error message is.

It is probably that you don't have the correct version of Java installed

Check this ticket for more if that is the case [How to call an embedded jre from command line in order to run java applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393930/how-to-call-an-embedded-jre-from-command-line-in-order-to-run-java-applications)

Comment: Ben Vosloo,

I solved the problem thanks to your information and the link to which you attached me. Check this ticket for more if that is the case How to call an embedded jre from command line in order to run java applications.

Specifically, I have reported in the same folder of my exported model the folder jre of my Anylogic, and in .bat file I have delete java version "-version: 1.6+".

I hope this note is clear and useful for others!